# How much wind power is there roughly in Britain and its surrounding?

Tags: climate-change

Given the prominence of the climate crisis, it's important to get some estimates of how much wind power is available in Britain as part of a renewably energised future.

**Q. What is yearly average of wind energy available on the landmass on Britain.**

**And how much does this work per metre squared?**

**More, given that for some they can be unsightly, how much yearly wind energy is available on the island shelf around Britain, say up to 30 km; and again what is the average per square metre? How does this compare with the yearly energy consumption in Britain?**

Thank you.

Comment: https://globalwindatlas.info/area/United%20Kingdom

Answer (score 4):

**2.2TWe** on average in the seas...

The uk uses less than 350 Gigawatts every year, so the sea can provide about 6 times the current UK energy consumption:

**80 GW in shallow waters (0-25 m)**

**270 GW in seas of depth 25-50m**

(up to there is sufficient to meet all of the UK's 2016 energy consumption)... There is also:

**790GW in seas of 50-100m**

**1030GW at 100m-700m**

https://claverton-energy.com/two-terawatts-average-power-output-the-uk-offshore-wind-resource.html

https://www.statista.com/statistics/323381/total-demand-for-electricity-in-the-united-kingdom-uk/

For onshore resources, you can add another 100GWh.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding renewable energies, there is a great book freely available:
https://www.withouthotair.com/
written by David MacKay. At the time he was the Regius Professor of Engineering at the University of Cambridge.

He estimated that onshore you can produce (realistically)

> if we covered the windiest 10% of the country with windmills
> (delivering 2 W/m2), we would be able to generate 20 kWh/d per person,
> which is half of the power used by driving an average fossil-fuel car
> 50 km per day.

(see https://www.withouthotair.com/c4/page_32.shtml and following pages)

Consumption in the UK was, at the time (2009), on average 195 kWh per day per person.